# Create a web page with prompts

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

My prompt boxes aren't working? Ever since I've put in the element stuff there not working.

I need prompt boxes so I can enter info and then that info to automatically go into a table and then it to automatically read the largest amount of $ by having a * in the row of the table. I'm not 100% on js coding so don't laugh if its a simple fix (it's the simple things that get me).

This is my code, I don't know what I've done wrong

"my table is in the head"

```
function money(){

this.currency = "";
this.amount = "";
this.exchangeRate = "";
this.ausDollars = "";

tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
  trElement = document.createElement('tr');
  tbody.appendChild(trElement);

// Read the 3 letter currency abbreviation entered
  currency = prompt('Please enter a 3-letter currency abbreviation', +i, "");
  // If the input data is invalid ask the user to re-enter it
  while (currency.length != 3) {
    currency = prompt('Currency abbreviation was not entered', "");
    currency = parseFloat(currency);
  }

currencyTH = document.createElement('th');
  currencyText = document.createTextNode(currency);
  currencyTH.appendChild(currencyText);
  trElement.appendChild(currencyTH);

 // Read the amount and convert it to entered currency 
  amount = prompt('Please enter an amount of money in that currency', +i, "");
  // If the input data is invalid ask the user to re-enter it
  while (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0) {
    amount = prompt('An amount of money was not entered')
    amount = parseFloat(amount);
  }

amountTH = document.createElement('th');
  amountText = document.createTextNode(amount);
  amountTH.appendChild(amountText);
  trElement.appendChild(amountTH);

 exchangeRateTH = document.createElement('th');
  exchangeRateText = document.createTextNode(exchangeRate);
  exchangeRateTH.appendChild(exchangeRateText);
  trElement.appendChild(exchangeRateTH);

}
```

Comment: you have a for loop that's creating a trElement 4 times,. but only doing something with the last one.  I assume your for loop want to be more like   `for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)  {`  notice the curly brace, you will of course require another closing curly brace at the end of your for loop.

Comment: So i have the closing curly brace after  tbody.appendChild(trElement); like this? tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
 for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) { 
   trElement = document.createElement('tr');
   tbody.appendChild(trElement);
 }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using **[`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)** to both prompt the user for input **and** display error messages in relation to user input. For that, you're looking for **[`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)**.

First you set the currency in a prompt with:

```
currency = prompt('Please enter a 3-letter currency abbreviation', +i, "");
```

Then you run:

```
 currency = prompt('Currency abbreviation was not entered', "");
```

This **overwrites** the value that was initially stored in `currency`, so you are unable to run `parseFloat()` on it on the next line:

```
 currency = parseFloat(currency);
```

To resolve this, use:

```
alert('Currency abbreviation was not entered');
```

Note that this is the same case for `amount`. Instead of:

```
amount = prompt('An amount of money was not entered');
```

Use:

```
alert('An amount of money was not entered');
```

Also note that your `while` loop structure is slightly wrong for indefinitely prompting until a correct value is met. Instead of initially prompting and then running your while loop, you should set a variable outside of the loop and then check the condition. And the `parseFloat()` **must** come outside of the `while` loop, or else you'll get stuck in an indefinite loop!

```js
var currency = '';
currency = prompt("Please enter 3 characters");
while (currency.length != 3) {
  alert('Currency must be three characters');
  currency = prompt("Please enter 3 characters");
}
currency = parseFloat(currency);

console.log("The stored value was: " + currency);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi, can i do this for the amount and exchangerate as well?

Comment: @Claire -- Yes, you will need to in order for that prompt to function correctly =]

Comment: like so? var amount = '';
 while (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0) {
    alert('An amount of money was not entered')
  }
   amount = parseFloat(amount);
   console.log("The stored value was: " + amount);                                                            var exchangeRate = '';
 while (isNaN(exchangeRate) || exchangeRate < 0) {
    alert('Exchange rate was not entered', "");
  }
    
 exchangeRate = parseFloat(exchangeRate);
    console.log("The stored value was: " + exchangeRate);

Comment: Close; as it turns out you'll actually need to call the alert **and** the `prompt()` again in the `while`. I've updated my answer to showcase this =]

Comment: Divide and conquer to isolate your problem. They are working in my example, so build from that.

Comment: Divide and conquer? im new to coding so your going to have to explain to me what you mean